# Draining a water heater

Tags: water, water-heater

We have a Rheem 111125 water heater and it started leaking tonight. I'm trying to drain out the tank so that I could replace the washer in the inlet tap, which isn't shutting off the supply at the moment. However, I can't seem to find the drain valve on the tank. Does anyone know how to drain out a Rheem water heater? Is draining actually needed to replace the supply tap? Here's a diagram

[image]

https://anodeswap.com/pdf/Rheemhwm-1.pdf

Any advice appreciated.

Comment: What they call an inlet should be the drain.  Make sure the breaker is off and open a hot water tap above to let in air.  If the inlet is not the drain, then it should be somewhere at the same level.  Only need to empty the tank to below the level of the leak.  Once fixed, fill the tank with the faucet still open to bleed out air.  Turn on tank.

Comment: Add a picture of the inlet.

Comment: @crip659 I took a leak of faith and opened up the supply valve anyway, and there was no burst. There's probably a one-way valve in the inlet. Now the washer is replaced. Thanks!

Comment: LOL "leak of faith" is certainly one way to put it.